# Bash: Read Variables from Text-File VAR=VALUE Format

Tags: linux, bash, parsing, variables, text-files

I want to load some variable from a text file into my batch script.
I tried searching but I only find tips for files like

```
VALUE1
VALUE2
...
```

**My** TEXT-File has the following format:

```
VER=123
MIN_VER=123456789
TARGET_VER=132456790
```

And I want to be able to load this file so that I can access the three variables for matching it against a number in bash.
How can I achieve this?

---

Answered! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save your variables to file like you want (VAR=VAL) and run:

```
. ./your_file
```

<strike>Maybe there will have to be"#!/bin/bash" at the beginning of this file.</strike> False

Comment: I have no control over the variables file (I try to match a plugin updater script against the version of the firmware image) - But as I call thet from /bin/bash it should work - if you're right - Waah I am stupid^^ It worked - Thx!