# Bash - get variables from an external file

Tags: bash, configuration

I'm trying to make a configuration file to help running a bash script.

The idea is having a file (script.conf) like this

```
directory=c:/path/to/a/specific/directory/
logo=y
title=y
hotspots=n
combobox=n
```

Then, running the script, it will read script.conf and get those variables to use in the script.

How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash: Read Variables from Text-File VAR=VALUE Format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11603349/bash-read-variables-from-text-file-var-value-format)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `source` command (also known as `.`, but not to be confused with the directory of the same name) will allow you to run another file in the current shell. Simply make that file contain variable assignments.

foo.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
. bar.sh
echo "$baz"
```

bar.sh

```
baz=42
```